# how do you find all DropDownList instances in a page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

the following one doesn't work:

```
        foreach (Control control in Controls) {
            if (control is DropDownList) {
                DropDownList list = control as DropDownList;
                ...
            }
        }
```

PS: My class extends `System.Web.UI.Page`

Answer (score 2):

You just need to replace Controls with Form.Controls

```
foreach (Control c in Form.Controls)
{
  if (c is DropDownList)
  {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Comment: Won't this break down if there are dropdownlists nested in other controls?

Comment: Agreed. I was just trying to point out the obvious problem with the code provided.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use this extension:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> AllControls<T>(this Control startingPoint) where T : Control
    {
        bool hit = startingPoint is T;
        if (hit)
        {
            yield return startingPoint as T;
        }
        foreach (var child in startingPoint.Controls.Cast<Control>())
        {
            foreach (var item in AllControls<T>(child))
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
```

Then you can use it for search of any type of System.Web.UI.Control within specific control. In case of DropDownList you can use it like:

```
IEnumerable<DropDownList> allDropDowns = this.pnlContainer.AllControls<DropDownList>();
```

- this will find all drop downs within Panel control with ID="pnlContainer".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that some of the DropDownList controls may be nested in other controls.

If you page has a panel and all of your controls are in that panel the page's control array will only have that panel and all of the control will be in the Panel's control array.

The link that ajax81 linked to will work well.